# Match non-English words using Regex in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex

Here is an example sentence:

```
क्या आप क्लोज़अप करते हैं
```

I want to extract the first word `क्या` from this sentence using Regex. I can do so in English by using `(^\w+)` but that doesn't work with other alphabets.

How should I proceed?

Answer (score 1):

You can add the `u` flag for Unicode support. That way you can specify patterns that include character properties, such as `\p{N}` for numbers in any language (Arabic, Chinese, ...).

```js
const str = 'क्या आप क्लोज़अप करते हैं ';

console.log('Letters and accent marks: ' + str.match(/^[\p{L}\p{M}]+/u))
console.log('Anything but space: ' + str.match(/^[^\p{Zs}]+/u))
```

Result:

```
Letters and accent marks: क्या
Anything but space: क्या
```

Explanation:

- both regex use `^` to anchor at the beginning
- regex 1: `[\p{L}\p{M}]+` - one or more letters and accent marks
- regex 2: `[^\p{Zs}]+` - anything that is not a space (includes all Unicode spaces)
- the `u` flag enables Unicode so that you can use `\p{...}` Unicode patterns

See details at https://javascript.info/regexp-unicode

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex to extract first word

```
^[\pL]+
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following regex

```
[^\x00-\x7F]+
```